# Jackson serialization duplicate field with @JsonAnyGetter

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jackson-databind

I have my DTO class with predefined fields and map for non-mapped. When otherFields map contains field with same name (field1 key) jackson serialize both of them and I have non-valid json like

```
{
"field1": "value",
"field1": "otherValue"
}
```

```
public class DTO implements Serializable {

    private String field1;

    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonAnySetter
    private final Map<String, Object> otherFields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getOtherFields() {
        return otherFields;
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }
}
```

Is there a way in this case pick one only value? For my case one from map should have priority.

Comment: To achieve this you should implement JsonSerializer for your DTO class write your logic 
inside the serialize method

Comment: @AbhisekLamsal is there any other sophisticated option? My class has a lot of fields and nested objects with same problem

Comment: I doubt there would be any other way for your particular problem. Another option can be adding JsonIgnore in all the fields and modifying the getters and setters such that you return value from the map in getters and add value to the map in all the setters. Either way you have to customize all the classes here

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I would propose is to ignore property and in `getter` marked by `JsonAnyGetter` annotation add extra logic which would check this condition:

```
class DTO {

    @JsonIgnore
    private String field1;

    private final Map<String, Object> otherFields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getOtherFields() {
        otherFields.putIfAbsent("field1", field1);

        return otherFields;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setOtherFields(String key, Object value) {
        otherFields.put(key, value);
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }
}
```

It is simple, but breaks `getter` by modifying `otherFields` `Map`. We can improve it by adding one classical `getter` and one for a `Jackson`:

```
class DTO {

    private String field1;
    private final Map<String, Object> otherFields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    public Map<String, Object> getOtherFields() {
        return otherFields;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    private Map<String, Object> internalJacksonGetOtherFields() {
        otherFields.putIfAbsent("field1", field1);

        return otherFields;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setOtherFields(String key, Object value) {
        otherFields.put(key, value);
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }
}
```